# Does the following system of linear equations contain infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Consider the following system of linear equations

$$
\begin{align}
x+y+z+w &= 2 \\
x- y+2z+3w &=-10 \\
x -3y+3z+5w &= -7 \\
x+3y- w &= -1
\end{align}$$

If we add the first two (solve for y) or the last two (solve for y), then both are same: $2x+3z+4w=-8$

Does it mean that all the points (a, y, b, c) are the solutions for the system of equations? Here $(a,b,c)$ is the point lying on the plane $2x+3z+4w=-8$ and $y$ is arbitrary.

Whereas, if we compute the row echelon form it says the rank of the coefficients matrix is 2 and the augmented matrix is 3. This implies the solution does not exist.

It seems confusing to me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Row reduction is the way to go; inspection won't get you very far for these kinds of problems. But if you want to take your method as far as you can, try to actually find a single solution.

Comment: For example, you claim that $(x,y,z,w) = (-4,0,0,0)$ is a solution since it lies on the hyperplane $2x+3z+4w = -8$, but surely you will agree that it does not solve *any* of the four equations.

Comment: @AlexProvost: Yes, I agree with you. But geometrically, the first addition of the equations says it is the intersection plane, similarly, for the second addition. Here, in my case, both the intersection-planes are overlapping. That is why I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a smaller toy example which, I believe, captures the essence of your problem (it is a system of four equations in two unknowns which is clearly inconsistent):

$$\begin{align}
x+y&=1\\
x+y&=2\\
x+y&=1\\
x+y&=2\\
\end{align}$$

Adding either the first or the last pair of equations together yields the line $2x+2y=3$. But you can't conclude anything about the solution space from this single equation. Really all you are saying is that *if* $(x,y)$ solves a pair of original equations, *then* it solves the new equation, but the converse is not true at all. What you *can* do with such a combination of two previous equations is substitute it in the original system (this is one of the elementary row operations), but then you still have to solve the system.

Comment: I think you get me wrong. For the first two equations, I solve for y. Similarly, for the last two equations, I also solved for y. This is not just an addition.

Comment: @Surojit I don't see the difference. Your hyperplane equation is obtained by adding together your first two equations, or your last two.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I understand that I wrote something "nonsense".